# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/upokecenter/cbor/CBORObject

Tags: java, maven, cbor

I'm trying to decode a QR code and I'm getting this runtime error while running this line
`Message a = Encrypt0Message.DecodeFromBytes(outputStream.toByteArray());`:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/upokecenter/cbor/CBORObject
    at cose.java@0.9.7/COSE.Message.DecodeFromBytes(Message.java:65)
    at cose.java@0.9.7/COSE.Message.DecodeFromBytes(Message.java:51)
    at kapta.classes/kapta.VerifyGreenPass.verify(VerifyGreenPass.java:44)
    at kapta.classes/kapta.DummyMainForVerifyGreenPass.main(DummyMainForVerifyGreenPass.java:6)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.upokecenter.cbor.CBORObject
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 4 more
```

I don't know why, because I've included all its dependencies by Maven pom.xml file:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.augustcellars.cose</groupId>
    <artifactId>cose-java</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.7</version>
</dependency>
```

I was following this tutorial  https://gae-piaz.medium.com/green-pass-qr-code-signature-verification-java-f742079cc88.
I've created a dummy project and there it seems to work, but in my main project it doesn't, caused by the error I've described before.

Comment: Please show how you **run** your application. The error means the class wasn't found at run time, which can happen if you forgot to specify the class path (or you have generated an executable jar, but its manifest doesn't specify the Class-Path, or the libraries specified in the manifest cannot be found)

Comment: I run it by IntelliJ IDE with a classic run configuration. What i can specify more? thanks

Comment: I only added the dependencies to the pom.fxml file without touching classpaths